# Adding node to xml output using for xml path

Tags: sql-server, xml, for-xml-path

I am creating an xml file using a `SELECT` statement and I am having trouble adding an extra node into the document.

The current structure created is this:

```
<DBObjectsToUpdate>
    <TablesToAdd>...</TablesToAdd>
    <TableObjectsToDelete> ...</TableObjectsToDelete>
    <Views>
        <View> </View>
    </Views>
    <StoredProcedures>   
        <StoredProc> </StoredProc>
    </StoredProcedures>
</DBObjectsToUpdate>
```

What I want to do is add a surrounding node around the 'Views' and 'StoredProcedures'. So it will look like this:

```
<DBObjectsToUpdate>
        <TablesToAdd>...</TablesToAdd>
        <TableObjectsToDelete> ...</TableObjectsToDelete>
        <TableObjectsToAdd> 
            <Views>
                <View> </View>
            </Views>
            <StoredProcedures>   
                <StoredProc> </StoredProc>
            </StoredProcedures>
        </TableObjectsToAdd>
    </DBObjectsToUpdate>
```

This is the relevant parts of the select statement:

```
SELECT 
    [Table].TableName AS "@TName", SchemaName AS "@Schema", 
    TextImageFileGroup AS "@TextImageOnFileGroup",
    ..bunch of stuff that is not important for this question
FROM
    ( a select statement to get the tables) AS [Table]

(--Returns all of the Triggers - Currently there are no triggers
SELECT 
    [Trig].TriggerName AS "@TriggerName",  
    [Trig].TrigDefinition AS "@TrigDefinition"
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT S7.TableName, S7.TriggerName, TrigDefinition 
     FROM #SourceDBObjects S7 
     JOIN #TableObjectsToAdd T7 ON S7.TableName = T7.TableName 
                                AND S7.TriggerName = T7.TriggerName 
                                AND T7.TriggerName IS NOT NULL) AS [Trig]
     WHERE 
         [Table].TableName = [Trig].TableName
     FOR XML PATH('Trigger'), TYPE) AS [Triggers]
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT T.TableName, S.SchemaName, S.TextImageFileGroup
     FROM #TableObjectsToAdd T 
     JOIN #SourceDBObjects S ON T.TableName = S.TableName)  AS [Table]
ORDER BY 
    "@TName"
FOR XML PATH ('Table'), TYPE) as [TableObjectsToAdd],
            (--Returns all of the check constrains for table
                    SELECT [CkCon].CheckName AS "@CkName", [CkCon].CkDefinition AS "@CkDefinition", [CkCon].IsCkDisabled AS "@IsCkDisabled"
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT T5.TableName, T5.CheckName, CkDefinition, IsCkDisabled
                          FROM #TargetDBObjects T5 JOIN #TableObjectsToDelete D5 ON T5.TableName = D5.TableName AND T5.DefaultName = T5.CheckName AND D5.CheckName IS NOT NULL) AS [CkCon]
                    WHERE [Table].TableName = [CkCon].TableName
                    FOR XML PATH('Check'),
                    TYPE
                ) AS [CheckConstraints]
        FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT D.TableName, T.SchemaName, T.TextImageFileGroup
                FROM #TableObjectsToDelete D JOIN #TargetDBObjects T ON T.TableName = D.TableName
             )  AS [Table]
        ORDER BY "@TName"
        FOR XML PATH ('Table'), TYPE)
        as [TableObjectsToDelete],
        (   ------VIEWS NODE------
             SELECT ObjectName AS "@VName", REPLACE(ObjectText, '''', '''''')  AS "@VDefinition"
             FROM #SourceViewsSPFunctionsToAdd 
             WHERE ObjectType = 'View'
             FOR XML PATH ('View'), TYPE
         ) AS [Views],
         (   ------STORED PROCEDURES NODE------
             SELECT ObjectName AS "@SPName", REPLACE(ObjectText, '''', '''''')  AS "@SPDefinition"
             FROM #SourceViewsSPFunctionsToAdd 
             WHERE ObjectType = 'StoredProcedure'
             FOR XML PATH ('StoredProcedure'), TYPE
          ) AS [StoredProcedures],
FOR XML PATH(''),
ROOT('DBObjectsToUpdate')
```

How do I encapsulate the views and stored procedures nodes into an outside node with has not elements or attributes?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out...Encapsulate the nodes using a `SELECT FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS [NameOfNode]`

So the part of the select statement in question looks like this:
...

```
(SELECT
 (   ------VIEWS NODE------
             SELECT ObjectName AS "@VName", REPLACE(ObjectText, '''', '''''')  AS "@VDefinition"
             FROM #SourceViewsSPFunctionsToAdd 
             WHERE ObjectType = 'View'
             FOR XML PATH ('View'), TYPE
         ) AS [Views],
         (   ------STORED PROCEDURES NODE------
             SELECT ObjectName AS "@SPName", REPLACE(ObjectText, '''', '''''')  AS "@SPDefinition"
             FROM #SourceViewsSPFunctionsToAdd 
             WHERE ObjectType = 'StoredProcedure'
             FOR XML PATH ('StoredProcedure'), TYPE
          ) AS [StoredProcedures],
 FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE) as [DBObjectsToAdd]
```

Comment: Greate! I hope you get the [self-learner-badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner). I'll give it a start: +1 :-)